# Authorization pop up while running spring boot application on tomcat 8

Tags: tomcat8

Required Authorization for executing application, which I am not sure what I need to put

Popped up message: The server localhost is asking for username and password.The server reports that it is from spring.

Warning: Your username and password will be sent using basic authentication on a connection that is not secure

Answer (score 2):

You should add `security.basic.enabled=false` in application.properties file and put it under src/main/resources path.